# Xcode Project Template: Add file to the project group

Tags: xcode, xcode-template

How do I make my custom Xcode project template add a file, e.g., `README.md`, to the project group (in the Project Navigator)?

The following steps puts the `README.md` file in the root project directory (on the filesystem) but in the group named after the target. How do I add it to the project group?

1. Add `README.md` to the project template's root directory.
2. Add the following key-value pairs to the `TemplateInfo.plist`.

   ```
   <key>Definitions</key>
   <dict>
       <key>../README.md</key>
       <dict>
           <key>Path</key>
           <string>README.md</string>
           <key>TargetIndices</key>
           <array/>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   ```

   and

   ```
   <key>Nodes</key>
   <array>
       <string>../README.md</string>
   </array>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can put README.md file into Project template/FolderName
2. add Definitions in  TemplateInfo.plist

   ```
   <key>FolderName/README.md</key>
   <dict>
       <key>Path</key>
       <string>FolderName/README.md</string>
       <key>Group</key>
       <array>
           <string>FolderName</string>
       </array>
   </dict>
   ```

and

3. add  Nodes

   ```
   <string>FolderName/README.md</string>
   ```